# Anyone know how to build a menu like this?

Tags: theming, routes, javascript

We are redesigning a site for a client and they're wanting to create a menu similar to the one found here (the big menu below the header, ***not*** the hamburger menu at the top left):

http://www.business.vic.gov.au/

Looks like it may have been built from scratch w/ jQ but thought someone might know of an existing module or theme that could get us started in the right direction.  Appreciate any advice or help.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackexchange. When asking a question **please** try to be as specific in your question as possible. Try describing what you want to know – also using screenshots or wireframes is ok – but please avoid forcing others to ckick on a link to understand your question. Questions like "How can I do `<link>`*this*`</link>`?" are usually not very likely to get a lot of attention from the community.

That said – I did click the link – and I suppose whether there is a module providing this effect/functionality or not is probably not that important since you could achieve a fairly similar effect with either a drupal menu or a drupal view **and** some javascript / jquery / ajax (for loading the second level dynamically) and some additional css3 for the sliding effect.

You could probably even skip the scripting part, display a standard list of links, hide the non-active second level items and use css3 to slide the second level in once it's needed. Asking ofer at stackexchange might be the more suitable forum to ask about this ([here is for example everything about 'slidetoggle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slidetoggle)).

I'm sorry this is probably not the answer you were looking for – but maybe if you provide more information on what you want to achieve someone else can point you to an appropriate module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Was just wanting some guidance on the direction to head so this was very helpful, actually.  Appreciate the advice on crafting questions and will keep that in mind in the future.  Cheers!

Comment: Great! Good luck! Cheers!